# Why cant AutoFac Resolve my class?

Tags: c#, autofac

I am having problems with AutoFac being able to resolve a constructor to resolve my type

I have a base type DataProviderBase

```
public abstract class DataProviderBase<TEntity>
  where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
  protected DataProviderBase()
  {
  }
}
```

This has an associated interface

```
public interface IDataProvider<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{

}
```

I then have BidDataProvider that inherits from this

```
public class BidDataProvider : DataProviderBase<Bid>, IBidDataProvider
{
    public BidDataProvider()
    {

    }
}
```

This has an associated interface

```
public interface IBidDataProvider : IDataProvider<Bid>
{

}
```

In my module I register the data provider

```
public class LivePriceManagerModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<BidDataProvider>()
            .As<IBidDataProvider>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

I then have an NServiceBus message handler which I need to get a BidDataProvider injected into

```
public class CreateBidHandler : IHandleMessages<CreateBid>
{
    private IBidDataProvider _bidDataProvider;

    public CreateBidHandler(IBidDataProvider bidDataProvider)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => bidDataProvider);

        _bidDataProvider = bidDataProvider;
    }
}
```

When I run my application I get the error below

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = CreateBidHandler (ReflectionActivator), Services = [NServiceBus.IHandleMessages`1[[Inspired.TradingPlatform.Messages.Commands.CreateBid, Inspired.TradingPlatform.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Handlers.CreateBidHandler], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Handlers.CreateBidHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.IBidDataProvider bidDataProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.IBidDataProvider)'. (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Handlers.CreateBidHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.IBidDataProvider bidDataProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.IBidDataProvider)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Does anyone know why my constructor cannot be found?

Autofac should be able to see it as BidDataProvider does not have a constructor that needs parameters

I have tried various combinations of concrete classes and interfaces in both the registration of the type and in the handler

Comment: From your error message it seems you are injecting `BidDataProvider` (concrete class), not `IBidDataProvider` (interface) to that constructor.

Comment: Code shows interface being used, but error message shows constructor accepts concrete class (unless I misinterpret a message). So I mean you maybe posted wrong code, and in real code handler accepts concrete class?

Comment: Ah I think I know whats happened, I think I changed the code but didnt re run it so you see the other message, I will try again.  I also tried playing with the registration but I get error System.ArgumentException: 'The type 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.IBidDataProvider' is not assignable to service 'Inspired.TradingPlatform.LivePriceManager.Services.BidDataProvider'.'
If I try to register interface and use concrete class inside the registration

Comment: You need to register like you do now, but accept `IBidDataProvider` in constructor. So basically code as you posted should work fine. And if it does not - please post correct error message.

Comment: It for some reason does not see your registration (from `IBidManager` to `BidManager`). Maybe you somehow have multiple containers? How do you register `CreateBidHandler ` itself?

Comment: I don’t specifically register CreateBidHandler it’s nservice bus that picks it up because it uses HandleMessages

Comment: But are you sure that NServiceBus and asp.net use the same autofac container in your case?

Comment: Yep I have also put a breakpoint on the registration and it does hit it

Comment: Is `CreateBidHandler` able to inject in other types successfully (i.e. is the problem related **specifically** to `IBidDataProvider` or more broadly)?

Comment: Fixed this - was caused by the assemblies not all being loaded.  We ensured that all the assemblies are loaded first and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to ensure that all of the assemblies are loaded when the application starts up.  Without this, the types are not registered properly